# CodeIgniter: get data after each 'foreach()' command

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->get("courses");
$data['courses'] = $query->result();
foreach($courses as $c){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('subjects');
    $this->db->where('id',$c->course);
    $query = $this->db->get("subjects");
    $data['subjects'] = $query->result();

    foreach($subjects as $s){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tests');
        $this->db->where('id',$t->test);
        $query = $this->db->get("tests");
        $data['tests'] = $query->result();
    }
}
```

I want to print tables of Courses having top first row with single column with data $c->course
and bellow rows with two column having data $s->subject and $t->test respectively...

Comment: You may do join between those three table and create an multidimensional array depend or course .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this for first row for **courses** and next two rows for **subjects** and **tests**

```
$query = $this->db->get("courses");
$data['courses'] = $query->result();
foreach($courses as $key=>$c){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('subjects');
    $this->db->where('id',$c->course);
    $query = $this->db->get("subjects");
    $data['subjects'][$key] = $query->result();

    foreach($subjects as $key=>$s){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tests');
        $this->db->where('id',$t->test);
        $query = $this->db->get("tests");
        $data['tests'][$key] = $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about echo. where should i put echo command to print course then its subjects and courses

Comment: you can print $data at end of the loop